# Display last post, PHP

Tags: php, mysql

So I finished a script to post a user's alliance news. They can keep posting new messages, but I'd like to find a way that it always displays the newest one on the main page of the alliance. This is my current setup:

id smallint (5) - This is the id of the alliance the users in
name varchar(30) - This is name of the alliance
news text - Of course the news to be posted
deleteid mediumint (10) AUTOINCREMENT - So users can delete their messages one by one

So how can I check to make sure it's the newest? Finding the highest deleteid matching their alliance's id or name works but should be an easier way. I also thought using datetime or don't know the code to check most recent according to that alliance id or name.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a timestamp column in your database.

It's really simple, just create your table like:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
mycols.....,
timedate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Then when you're selecting from the table, and you want the most recent:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE something = something-else
ORDER BY timesdate DESC --Orders results from most recent to least recent
LIMIT 1; -- just want the first row
```

Also, maybe try and post some code for a question like this in future as opposed to just a body of text :)

Comment: Thank you! This is my first post

Comment: No Problem! Maybe you could click the tick beside my answer to mark it as correct :)